# PHP If Value Equals 1 Then Define Variable, Else Do Nothing

Tags: php

Here's what I came up with and wondering if there is a more eloquent way to accomplish the below or if this is acceptable?

Update using Ternary Operators:

```
$fbpid = ($_GET['fbt'] == 1) ? ("123456") : (NULL);
echo $fbpid;
```

What I originally had:

```
$fbt = $_GET['fbt'];

if ($fbt == 1) {
    $fbpid = "123456";
}
else {$fbpid = NULL;}

echo $fbpid;
```

Comment: You could use ternary operator.. or null coalescing if using PHP 7.

Comment: This doesn't check if the value exists, it checks if the variable is equal to something equivalent to the number 1.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer oops, i'll update the title. thanks

Comment: I actually prefer the longer (to write) way.  I would normally actually put the else block the same as you did with the if block.  I do this because it lowers the cognitive load when you're trying to debug the logic at 3 am.

Comment: @user3783243 Updated code above with use of ternary operators to the best of my ability.

Comment: Both codes work well and are correct, for these cases personally I prefer Ternary Operators since they occupy less lines of code, but that is not very important, the main thing is that it is understandable :)

Comment: Great, thank for the feedback and confirming I'm on the right track @AndrésR.C.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fbt = $_GET['fbt'];
$fbpid = null;

if ($fbt == 1) 
{
    $fbpid = "123456";
}

echo $fpbid;

// output: 123456
```